# How can Text Segment be accidentally edited in memory layout?

Tags: c, memory-management, stack, heap-memory, memory-layout

So While digesting the memory layout thing, i stumbled upon a very interesting statement that is:  **In the text section of the final executable object file, we only have read and execute permissions and no write permissions. This is done to prevent accidental modifications to the corresponding assembly code.**, ok given that text segment is positioned far from the heap and stack, and no heap/stack overflow could effect our central instructions what could 'accidentally', modify our text segment? some code examples would be very appreciated?

Comment: That can easily occur by malicious code just setting a pointer to a text address and by accident due to memory bugs (buffer overflow, memory corruption, etc).

Answer (score 0):

> How can Text Segment be accidentally edited in memory layout?

The most common error is of course writing to a string literal. String literals are immutable, readonly. Sadly, in the C language string literals are not `const` pointers and can be assigned to a `char*` pointer. With gcc make sure you use `-Wwrite-strings` warning. A common beginner error is to think arrays auto-resize:

```
char *str = "Hello";
strcat(str, " world!"); // WRONG!
```

Example with ex. strtok:

```
char *str = "this is a string";
strtok(str, " "); // WRONG!
```

etc.

> some code examples would be very appreciated?

There can be **many** code examples that try to write to text segment. You can write to a memory location uninitialized pointer and you do not know where you write to:

```
void foo() {
   int *a;
   *a = 42;
}
```

And I personally like the unpredictability of `rand()`:

```
int *a = (int*)rand();
*a = 42;
```

Such code can write to **any** possible location.